# Simple linear map question

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

I am struggling with a very simple question. I need to show that any linear map $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ has the form:

$$f(z)=\alpha z+\beta\, \bar z,\quad \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$$

I thought of relating this to an arbitrary matrix but I can't see how to do it. Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you mean linear with respect to $\mathbb{R}$? That's the only thing that makes sense here.

Comment: $\mathbb C$-linear or $\mathbb R$-linear?

Comment: @David Yes with respect to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Say the linear mapping has matrix $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$. See how you have to pick the complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that the effect of $f$ on $z = x + iy$ is the same as the effect of the linear mapping. Basically, you need to translate the expression for $f(z)$ into formulas involving coordinates.

Comment: @David This is what I'm confused about. If $\alpha=a+bi$ and $\beta=c+di$ I can see that $f(z)=(a+c)x+(d-b)y+i(b+d)x+i(a-c)y$ but how can I relate this to a matrix? Or am I not heading in the right direction?...

Comment: Can you write $\alpha = e + fi, \beta = g + hi$ and then pick $e, f, g, h$ so that they match the effect of the matrix? They might not be $a, b, c, d$.

Comment: The matrix above takes $(x,y)$ to $(ax + by, cx + dy)$. This is written in terms of coordinates. But there is no difference between $x$- and $y$-coordinates on the one hand, and real and imaginary parts on the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is $\mathbb R$-linear, we have $f(\lambda \cdot z) = \lambda \cdot f(z)$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. Hence, for $z = x+iy$ we get
\begin{align*}
f(z) & = f(x+iy) = f(x) + f(iy) \\
& = f(x \cdot 1) + f(y \cdot i) \\
& = x \cdot f(1) + y \cdot f(i).
\end{align*}

This way we see that $f$ is completely defined by defining the values of $f(1)$ and $f(i)$. So let's find out if we can this by choosing some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb C$ such that $f(z) = \alpha z + \beta \bar z$.

We want
\begin{align*}
f(z) & = xf(1) + yf(i) \\
& = \alpha z + \beta \bar z \\
& = \alpha x + \alpha i y + \beta x - \beta i y\\
& = (\alpha + \beta) x + i(\alpha - \beta) y
\end{align*}
Now all you have to do is solve the equation system
\begin{align*}
f(1) & = \alpha + \beta\\
f(i) & = i(\alpha - \beta)
\end{align*}
for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and you see that you can define any $\mathbb R$-linear map $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ as $f(z) = \alpha z + \beta \bar z$.